# CSS/Javascript code to provide image border for many sizes of HTML div

Tags: javascript, css, user-interface

I'm intending to write a HTML5/Javascript game to run in modern browsers.  It will need dialog boxes (i.e. modal popups) whose borders would be made of images (e.g. one for the vertical, one for the horizontal, one for each corner).  The popups, and therefore border, should contain and size to a div (containing text or whatever).  There will be lots of different size popups.  So I can provide (repeatable?) images from which the borders should be made, but I don't want to create an image for every size of popup that I need in my game.

I hope that my requirements are clear enough.  Can I do this with just CSS?  Are there some sample CSS 'libraries' to do this?  Or do I need to use Javascript (or a combination of CSS and Javascript) and, again, if so there any example or libraries I can use?

Comment: If browser requirements permit - take a look at [border-image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image)

Comment: Thanks.  I think I need to throw my browser net wider in this case. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this pure css by assigning each type of element (left border, lower left corner) etc a class and then setting the background image and width/height of the css for that class to the image and dimensions you require.